# How can I display items of Collection View one by one in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms

(I need a delay of few seconds while displaying the Collection View Items)
**Here is my code

```
 public async void GetData()
        {
            var result = await _rest.GetUserInfo();
            if (result.Count>0)
            {
                IsBusy = false;
            }
            UserDetail = new ObservableCollection<User_Info>(result as List<User_Info>);
            TempUserInfo = UserDetail;
            
        }


<CollectionView x:Name="mycolview" 
                           
                            SelectionMode="None"
                            ItemsSource="{Binding TempUserInfo}"
                            Margin="0,10">
```

Comment: you will need to add items your ObservableCollection one at a time with a delay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 var result = await _rest.GetUserAlbum(Userid);       
                AlbumInfo = new ObservableCollection<UserAlbumInfo>(result as List<UserAlbumInfo>);
                if (AlbumInfo.Count > 0)
                {
                    IsBusy = false;
                }
                foreach (var item in AlbumInfo)
                {
                    TempAlbumInfo.Add(item);
                    await Task.Delay(1000);
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `Task.Delay` to make a delay of few seconds while displaying the Collection View Items.

```
 public async void GetData()
    {
        await Task.Delay(5000);
        var result = await _rest.GetUserInfo();
        if (result.Count>0)
        {
            IsBusy = false;
        }
        UserDetail = new ObservableCollection<User_Info>(result as List<User_Info>);
        TempUserInfo = UserDetail;
        
    }
```

Comment: It will not work, because it will add delay only one time when the GetaData() method is called.

Comment: What kind of delay do you want?

Comment: I want to display the collection view item one by one